# Rails.cache.delete does not work (Dalli store)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, dalli

Hi I ma new to rails and I try to delete a key from the rails cache like  this:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('datasources_field_options')
```

I see a big array in the rails console
Then I try to delete it like this:

```
 Rails.cache.delete('datasources_field_options')
```

This returns `true`
this is from the console:

```
irb(main):004:0> Rails.cache.delete('datasources_field_options')
2019-09-26 14:45:56 +0000 1569509156754 (24618) Cache delete: datasources_field_options
=> true
irb(main):005:0>
```

And then I check again if it was deleted:

```
Rails.cache.fetch('datasources_field_options')
```

The cache type is `ActiveSupport::Cache::DalliStore`

No it wasn't. The array is still there.

What am I missing? Why cant delete the specific key from the cache?

**EDIT**
I checked the configuration - the store is configured to use Redis on a remote host.
I did a quick video to show you what I am doing.

https://youtu.be/q2WyYniacNw

Comment: Is the `datasources_field_options` a key you put in or was it already present?

Comment: It was present.